# How to send a voicemail for outbound call in twilio when machine answer?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

hello I'm currently developing dialer using Twilio API, how can I drop a voice message when machine answered the call?

i already tried searching documentation but i can't find any.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what kind of voice message you mean?

This piece of code on TypeScript can help with first half of the your issue:

```
// create a call with certain parameters: 

const twilioClient = twilio(accountSid, authToken)

const call = await twilioClient.calls.create({
      // another fields
      machineDetection: 'Enable', // https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection#machinedetection
      asyncAmd: 'true', // enable amd handling
      asyncAmdStatusCallback: `url/amd`, // here you put a full or relative endpoint link to handle amd status, when it changes
      
      // another useful parametes
      machineDetectionTimeout: 30,
      machineDetectionSpeechThreshold: 2000,
      machineDetectionSpeechEndThreshold: 2500,
      machineDetectionSilenceTimeout: 4000,
})
```

```
// router file

import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/amd', amdHelper)

async function amdHelper(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  const { CallSid, AccountSid, AnsweredBy, MachineDetectionDuration } = req.body
  try {
    if (AnsweredBy.includes("machine") || AnsweredBy == "fax") {
      console.log(`[CallSid] Call was answered by machine. AnsweredBy: ${AnsweredBy}`)

      const status = await twilioClient.calls(CallSid).update({
          status: 'completed',
      })

      // drop a voice message ...

      return res.json(status)
    } else return res.status(200).json({})
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error)
  }
}
export default router
```